# regular expression that ignores case of first character

Tags: javascript, regex

I know JavaScript regular expressions can ignore case for the entire match, but what about just the first character? Then **hello World!** would match **Hello World!** but not **hello world!**.

Comment: @Richard: you keep commenting that it's not what you want but can you more precise?  Basically from your question, just take your *"regular expression that can be applied to all words"* [sic] and that doesn't work (or you wouldn't be asking the question) and add [a-zA-Z] in front of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it another way. Force the first character of your data string to lower case before matching it against your regular expression. Here's how you'd do it in ActionScript, JavaScript should be similar:

```
var input="Hello World!";
var regex=/hello World!/;
var input2 = input.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase() + input.substr(1);
trace(input2.match(regex));
```

Comment: yeah, guess I'll just do it directly

Answer (score 6):

You mean like `/[Tt]uesday/`

The [Tt] creates a set, which means either 'T' or 't' can match that first character.

Comment: This question had zero answers when I clicked on it. Now two. I fail to snipe easy points yet again :(

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-z]
```

Comment: the word may contain capitals and punctuation

Comment: That's a direct contradiction of the requirements as stated in your question.

Comment: @Richard, can you provide me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't really make sense.  Since the edit, it now says "I am after a general regular expression that can be applied to all words.".  The regex to match all words and punctuation would be ".*"

What are you trying to match?  Can you give examples of what should match and what should not match?

Answer (score 1):

#### regular-expressions.info

- [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

  > With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`. You could use this in `gr[ae]y` to match either `gray` or `grey`.

---

Thus, a regex that matches `Tuesday` and `tuesday`, and nothing else, is `[Tt]uesday`.

---

If you're given an arbitrary word `w`, and a subject `s` that needs to match `w`, except that the first letter is case-insensitive, then you don't really need regular expressions. Just check that the first letter of `w` and `s` is the same letter, ignoring case, then make sure that the substring of `w` and `s` from index `1` matches exactly.

In Java, it'd look something like this:

```
boolean equalsFirstLetterIgnoreCase(String s, String w) {
   return s.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase().equals(w.substring(0, 1).toLowerCase())
     && s.substring(1).equals(w.substring(1));
}
```